# In MYSQL is it better to have one big table or many smaller tables

Tags: mysql

I am making a database of my client's customers to send email promotions to. The database will include all about 12 of my clients and each of them has an average of 2100 customers. I was wondering if it would be better to have a table in the db for each one of my clients that contains a list of their customers or if I should just make one big table...

The customers will be queried daily.

I know it is a broad question but any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Chuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`12 * 2100 = 25200` records which is peanuts for every modern database (if you provide appropriate indexes, that is).

So make it one big table (if this will ease the querying and it is a sort of ad hoc table).

EDIT: otherwise I'd take the normalize path as duffymo suggested.

Comment: I ended up using one big table for all of them. There are a few repeat customers but out of the 25000, only about 10.

Comment: For the mail server I am using SendGrid - they kick ass

Answer (score 5):

> 12 of my clients and each of them has
>   an average of 2100 customers

This is an easy call: it's a one-to-many relationship between clients and customers, so why not have two tables with a foreign key relationship between them?  The JOIN won't cost you much.  I'd recommend normalizing it.  The number of rows is trivial.

Make sure you add a UNIQUE constraint to the email address column in the customer table.

Answer (score 3):

You won't have to worry about database performance either way, but about the number of E-Mails you send out - 25,200 E-Mails is going to put a lot of strain on your mail server.

There may be another reason to keep separate tables, though: The E-Mail addresses you work with are confidential data from separate clients. It stands to reason that keeping separate tables is an additional layer helping to prevent mix-ups. Also, tables (=clients) can easily be dumped, dropped and/or added that way.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have one big table and several Views. 
you will be able to do insert, update, delete directly from view.